# docker-compose api call from one container to another in the same network

Tags: docker, rest, docker-compose

I have 2 different component/images and following docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
    my_service:
        image: my_service:latest
        restart: always
        environment:
            - DUMMY=dummy
        ports:
            - "8071:8071"
        command: ""
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/bin ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
        container_name: my-service-container
        networks:
            - my_net

    my_ui:
        image: my_ui:latest
        depends_on:
            - my_service
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: ""
        networks:
            - my_net
networks:
    my_net:
        driver: bridge
```

"my_ui" component is a ui (angular code) which calls services from "my_service" component.
When I call using the "real" host name (server where all deployment is there) it works i.e.

E.g.

Hostname (Linux): real.host.name

Docker is installed and running on above host. I run docker-compose up on the above host so my dontainers are up and running.

From another machine or host I call the following via postman, and it works.

(POST request, has raw body as required, etc).

```
http://real.host.name:8071/api/auth/login
```

The above call works. However, I want to use the docker service name for such calls so deployment to multiple host/env is smooth.

When I try the below, it does not work:

```
http://my_service:8071/api/auth/login
```

It fails

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

When I go to "my_ui"

```
docker exec -it rm <container name of my_ui> /bin/bash

$ ping my_service
```

The above works fine i.e. ping is good. However, when I make the http request it does not recognize the "my_service" host.

Can someone help here?

Comment: Where is the actual application running?  If it's something like a `fetch` or XHR call from a browser, that's outside Docker, and it can't use the Docker-internal service names.  In that context the `real.host.name` and the published `ports:` are the correct approach.

Answer (score -1):

I think that service name resolution is purely internal when using bridge mode, that would be why you can ping a service using its name from a container but cannot get a ICMP reply when pinging from Host.

So the my_ui container is able to make requests to my_service container from Docker bridge network, but not from host (at least not with service name resolution).

If your concern is that you want to be able to use the same service whether it is from a different host or not, I suggest using Docker in Swarm mode for such use-case. This way you would be able to use the same service based on a port rather than on a service name.

I wrote a step by step guide last year about Docker Swarm if that can be of any interest :)
https://pat-laboratory.com/2020/11/03/docker-swarm-introduction-workshop/

Let me know if this was of any help or if I completely missed the point of your question!